# Group team site home.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages

The standard system provisioned home.aspx page on a group team site uses a different layout than a manually created modern page. Most noticably it lacks the header with the page name but the content area is also a bit wider. There might be more differences.

I would like to use the same template to create a new home page for our main root site tenantname.sharepoint.com. Is that possible? I'd also would like to use that template to create regular modern pages in a site if possible.